# Eh, codegolf shmodegolf

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing

This challenge is about implementing [Shm-reduplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shm-reduplication), originating in Yiddish, where one takes a word, duplicates it, and replaces the first syllable in the second word with "Shm" in order to indicate that one does not care. Some examples include:

- "Isn't the baby cute?", "Eh, baby shmaby"
- "Come buy from my store, we have a sale!", "Pff, sale shmale"
- "I got this smartphone yesterday, isn't it cool?", "Meh, smartphone shmartphone"

## Rules

In the real world there are a bunch of [special cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shm-reduplication#Phonological_properties), but for this challenge we will use rules that describe a simplified version of the full linguistic phenomenon that is more suitable for programming:

1. Consonants up to first vowel are replaced by "shm".
2. Prepend shm to words beginning with vowels.
3. If a word contains no vowels it is returned unchanged. No vowel, no shm.
4. The vowels are: a, e, i, o, u.
5. The input will be restricted to lowercase letters.
6. The output should be a lowercase string containing the reduplicated version of the input. **If the input is "string" the output should be "shming"**.

This is code golf, shortest code wins!

## Example solution (ungolfed python)

This is an example of code that would solve the challenge:

```python
def function_shmunction(string):
    vowels = "aeiou"
    for letter in string:
        if letter in vowels:
            index = string.index(letter)
            shming = "shm" + string[index:]
            return shming
    return string
```

## Test cases

- function -> shmunction
- stellar -> shmellar
- atypical -> shmatypical
- wwwhhhat -> shmat
- aaaaaaaaaa -> shmaaaaaaaaaa
- lrr -> lrr
- airplane -> shmairplane
- stout -> shmout
- why -> why

An answer has been accepted since there haven't been any new responses in a while, but feel free to add more!

Comment: I've made a minor edit to your post, since the Zsh answer seems to think you should output the input + a space. If I misunderstood something and my edit is incorrect, feel free to revert it.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen No, you're correct. I might have been a bit unclear about that in the text.

Comment: Suggested test case: one that starts with multiple different vowels (my initial approach failed for it but succeeded for all other test cases). E.g. `aeiou -> shmaeiou` or `airplane -> shmairplane`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Added! I also included one that has a vowel directly after the first vowel.

Comment: @jezza_99 [the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/24781#24781) actually had the same output format as this post, I believe my formatting of the explanation of the real world phenomenon was done carelessly and so was easy to interpret as the intended output format.

Comment: must. resist. changing. sh. to. sch. to. match. local. accent.

Comment: Bylaws, shmaws!  Nothing like a little oversimplification to brighten your day!  Flypaper, shmaper!  Lymphatic, shmatic! Syzygies, shmies!  There's probably a good puzzle in there somewhere.  Surely syzygy shmyzygy is an expression that should not be lost to posterity.

Comment: @phoog The original reason I omitted y was that I am uncertain of its position as a vowel in the English language as a non-native speaker. I agree that some very amusing examples are lost when you ignore y like this, but I do not think it's a good idea to change the rules this far into the challenge.

Comment: @JSorngard indeed.  It's not easy to tell algorithmically when y is a vowel and when it is a consonant.  Backyard and dyad come to mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ÄFï¥░$º{═┘ç
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8e468b9db024a77bcdd987&i=function%0Astellar%0Aatypical%0Awwwhhhat%0Aaaaaaaaaaa%0Alrr%0Aairplane%0Astout%0Awhy%0A&a=1&m=2)

1. Left-trim consonants.
2. If non-empty, prepend "shm".
3. Else restore original input.

Answer (score 12):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 29 bytes

```
s/[^aeiou]*\([aeiou]\)/shm\1/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYvRCsMgDEXf8yXbYMi@RzsIzjaBLIpGpF/fCoXepwPn3JZ@7037cTTnv5g49@UVHv6i8HSN/uHjprbKusHaNRpnhWZJBCug7YUjCowxiAgN8B5InQHXIqhpPnI3GLSf)

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>16</s> 12 bytes

```
œlØḄṭ⁸¹?“shm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o5JzDMx7uaHm4c@2jxh2Hdto/aphTnJH7/1HD3Ic7px1awvVwx6bD7Y@a1nj//59Wmpdckpmfp1BcAtScWKSQWFJZkJmcmKNQXl6ekZGRWKKQCAcKOUVABZlFBTmJealAHfmlJQA)

*-4 thanks to ovs remembering there's a strip builtin*

```
œlØḄ            Strip all leading consonants.
    ṭ   “shm    Prepend "shm"
      ¹?        if there's anything left, otherwise
     ⁸          give the original word.
```

Comment: Porting Jitse's Python answer gives 14 bytes: `œlØḄ“shm”;$⁸Ẹ?`

Comment: I was about to suggest you post that yourself until I realized what builtin it leans on... :facepalm:

Answer (score 10):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 50 bytes

```hs
snd.break(`elem`"aeiou")>>=(?)
""?s=s
r?_="shm"++r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BDoIwDIbvPkXTcICgPoEbL6Anj2K04JDFMZZ1hPjyTqbG/9D/a/unaU/8UMbETtSR7W3beEWP/KqMGq5ISo8TFlKKvCpWiBULXvnqIpD7AcvSx4G0BQEDuQO4KRyD31vIIK8ZNhIYyhIQhFzKQh1wAbtMwgnn0d9wDdhQ80zOZNTHg9f2nqibbBv0aL/T5UXyCSk8nW7JJJ7nuV9E4bP4K3UmfNPaO0P2d3qcAp7jq@0M3TluWufe)

*Thanks to Roman Czyborra for -2 bytes*

Comment: 50: span.notElem==break.elem

Answer (score 9):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 25 bytes

```
/[aeiou]/s/[^aeiou]*/shm/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYtBCoAwDMDufYogfZAoFJ22UDtZO4avn4JgTjkknrbxsNo7TpQk1xkdp@XTAZ1P7N2jiB2wV1tDsoFHUqUCFPclKym01piZAugHtLyBlEvJ0nvkGtD4fgA)

`/[aeiou]/` is a conditional that only runs the substitution `s/[^aeiou]*/shm/` if there is a vowel in the line. This prevents needing to capture the first vowel and then using a backreference as in the more obvious `s/[^aeiou]*\([aeiou]\)/shm\1/`.

Answer (score 7):

## [Powershell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 36 bytes

```
$args-replace('^.*?([aeiou])','shm$1')
```

#### Explanation

Simple replace with a named group reference.

[+4](https://tio.run/#%23K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL042iBWtyi1ICcxOVVDXSNOT8s@OjE1M780VlNdR704I1fFUF3z////SiAt@UoA)

Thanks [caird coinheringaahing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66833/caird-coinheringaahing)

[-5](https://tio.run/#%23K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL1Ytyi1ICcxOVVdI05Pyz46MTUzvzRWU11HvTgjV8VQ/f///0og1flKAA)

Thanks [mazy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8745/mazzy)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833)! Currently, this answer does not meet our standard rules: 1) this doesn't [appear to work](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvUqFgq6AEYuYrATm6RakFOYnJqRrqGnHRiamZ@aWxmuo66sUZuSqG6pr//wMA) unless the input begins with a vowel, and 2) this assumes the input is saved in the `$x` variable, which is not an acceptable form of input. Both of these can be corrected for [+9 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL042iBWtyi1ICcxOVVDXSNOT8s@OjE1M780VlNdR704I1fFUF3z////SiAt@UoA)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Thank you so much. Can I use your answer? I was really struggling to find a good example of how to use the test it out website. And how powershell answers should be formatted.

Comment: @anothervictimofthemouse You're welcome to use the program I linked to. You can find an answer template on that site if you click the link button, and scroll down to the "Code Golf Answer" option. You can also find formatting tips in the "Answering" post in the Welcome page I linked

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I got the regex wrong: it should be `^.*?([aeiou])` in the replacement stage

Comment: you can save 5 bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL1Ytyi1ICcxOVVdI05Pyz46MTUzvzRWU11HvTgjV8VQ/f///0og1flKAA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 62 bytes

```python
lambda s:(q:=s.lstrip('bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'))and'shm'+q or s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVC7csQgEOv5iu3Ak8s1aTKeId2lTZMyDbZxIIcBL@v4nJ938FPNSlqNliFOZIJ/eY04t/JrdqqrGgWpFH0p09UlQhsFr@qm/TY/d9f52GOi3/Ex/fGiUL7hyXT8qYeAkObRWKfhEwddMgDCaRkA1scLhIFALnQgUVxTdJYEh@c34MUaQp1ghYRW5NjmRrSeRN5JmQsuW1WWy1Y/ah0Jbh/vN8SA260KtbrP7eBrssEv/fmBu2KJtHMKd3flTNEUba3cbh6SjeNojFF0@kydOLwTzOHamgdTFqNTXh@hXebjyxdsZmb/)

Answer (score 6):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 36 bytes

```
<<<${(S)1/#(#b)*([aeiou])/shm$match}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwU3f4tSS_IIShdSKktS8lNSU9Jz8JK60_CIFQwWN5PyU1PT8nDSF4pLUnJzEIoXEksqCzOTEHIVEMFDIKSrSLCjKzCtJU1AxjFFQU1taWpKma3FTxcbGRqVaI1jTUF9ZQzlJU0sjOjE1M780VlO_OCNXJTexJDmjFqJ2AZSC0gA)

- `<<<`: print
- `${1}`: the input...

  - `//`: replace the first match

    - `#`: matching only at the beginning of the string
    - `(#b)`: activate backreferences, so the `()` group gets stored in the `$match` variable
    - `(S)`: use the shortest possible match, rather than the longest
    - `*`: anything
    - `()`: store this match in the variable:

      - `[aeiou]`: followed by a vowel
  - with `shm$match`: the string `shm`, plus the matched vowel

`$match` is actually an array which contains all the backreference groups, but since there's only one group, we don't need to access any specific element with `[1]`

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 15 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
r"^.*?%v"ÈÌi`¢m
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ciJeLio/JXYiyMxpYKJt&input=WwoiZnVuY3Rpb24iCiJzdGVsbGFyIgoiYXR5cGljYWwiCiJ3d3doaGhhdCIKImFhYWFhYWFhYWEiCiJscnIiCiJhZXJvcGxhbmUiCiJzdG91dCIKIndoeSIKXQotbVI) (Includes all test cases)

```
r"^.*?%v"ÈÌi`¢m     :Implicit input of string
r                   :Replace
 "^.*?%v"           :  RegEx /^.*?[aeiou]/gi
         È          :  Pass each match through a function
          Ì         :    Last character
           i        :    Prepend
            `¢m     :      Compressed string "shm"
```

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>28</s> 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
žNSÛ©ai®…shmì
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9vc2FiaWX//8W@TlPDm8KpYWnCruKApnNobcOs//9hdHlwaWNhbA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/6P7/IIPzz60MjHz0LpHDcuKM3IPr/lfq/M/Wqk8vyhFSUdBKSkxqRJEFyfmpILpkqLMvHQQK600L7kkMz8PIpqak5NYBGImllQWZCYn5oDY5eXlGUCQWAKWgAMQL6cEojqzqCAnMQ9qdH5piVIsAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
žNSÛ           # Trim all leading consonants of the (implicit) input-string
    ©          # Store this new string in variable `®` (without popping)
     ai        # Pop, and if any letters are left (thus the input-string contains
               # a vowel):
       ®       #  Push string `®` again
        …shmì  #  Prepend "shm"
               #  (implicitly print it as result)
               # (implicit else)
               #  (implicitly output the implicit input-string)
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 48 bytes

```hs
g.break(`elem`"aeiou")
g(s,"")=s
g(_,r)="shm"++r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BDoIwDIbvPkXTeICAPoHjCfTkUY0UHLA4xrKOEF/euaHxP/T/2v5pOhA/pdahE9fQ7xsn6ZnVUsuxRpJqmjHf9BmXiLngSPfS5QJ5GLEoXBhJGRAwkj2Bnf3Zu6OBLWRXhl0FDEUBCKKKJVIHnMNhW8EFl8k9sARsqHklZ9Jyde@U6RN1s2m9msx3Gh8kl5D8y6qWdOJlWYYo8uvir9Rp/00rZzWZ3@lp9ngL77bT1HPYtdZ@AA)

Comment: I forgot about your comment but I would have encouraged you to post an answer so I'm glad you did! Nice find, it's funny how `span` being shorter than `takeWhile` or `dropWhile` encourages you to use both parts even if you can make do with one.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 53 bytes

```
lambda s:re.sub("^.*?([aeiou])","shm\\1",s)
import re
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYxNCgIhGED3neLDlcYktAhCiA6SBU6jjeAfnwp2ljZC1J26TcT0Nm_13uOd7mWOoT_NQb5qMZv9Z-eUHycFWaDmuY6UXPj6SE9K21jPjAwkz17KLRkyW1mfIhZA_Y-FiQgNbCDXOOlbdAZy0c4pBPUDHCLhOTlbKBMJbSi0DYY2xpZD74u_)

Another regex answer.

---

Alternative:

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 53 bytes

```
lambda s:re.sub(".*?(?=[aeiou])","shm",s,1)
import re
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYxNCgIhGED3neLDlYYJLYIQhjlItXAabQT_-FSws7QRou7UbSKmt3mr9x7vdC9LDP1phvOrFrM7fg5O-WlWkCVqketEidiOdBxOSttYL4xwkhdPeOZ7trE-RSyA-h9LExEa2ECucda36Azkop1TCOoHOEQicnK2UCYT2lBo44Y2xtZD76u_)

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 13 bytes

```
k⁰øl:[«88«p|_
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCLGmyIsImvigbDDuGw6W8KrODjCq3B8XyIsIl07WsabYCA9PiBgajvigYsiLCJbXCJ3b3JkXCIsIFwiYmFieVwiLCBcInNhbGVcIiwgXCJzdHJpbmdcIiwgXCJmdW5jdGlvblwiLCBcInN0ZWxsYXJcIiwgXCJhdHlwaWNhbFwiLCBcInd3d2hoaGhhdFwiLCBcImFhYWFhYWFhYWFcIiwgXCJsdHJcIiwgXCJhaXJwbGFuZVwiLCBcInN0b3V0XCJdIl0=)

Port of Jelly.

### How?

```
k⁰øl:[«88«p|_
k⁰øl           # Strip leading consonants
    :[         # If there's anything left:
      «88«p    # Prepend "shm"
           |_  # Else, pop, returning the implicit input
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 19 bytes

Just a regex replacement, there might be some language feature which allows for a shorter solution.

```
^.*?(?=[aeiou])
shm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcFRCoAgDADQ/53E@gg6QHiQKBpibDA1dCKdfv31Xo3KGVdL7gI7l9k7v@0YufRjgkbJ7O45KJcMTaMIVkB9Hw4oMMYgIlTAH0itHw)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, 36 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/.*?([aeiou])/,"shm$1")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY1RDsIgEETvQvwAozQeoHoQbdINboVmyxKgkp4eaT@cr5nJm8wMX0gmupCvnt9Yp76m/p50xEBgUHb6/JBPQMfroLqLSHY53YSqhn1iQk38kU8xrd5kx140ICMRxOYgb8EZoGZLKdZayHv7VwsUDxAjtzePx5zXHSt2E4NeIMhJ6ZmdH19@VPUH) (includes all test cases)

Comment: Why u need the `^`?

Comment: Possibly a holdover from my Japt solution, @l4m2, where it's cheaper to use `^` than it is to disable the `g`lobal flag, which is enabled by default. Ping me on Monday to remind me to investigate properly.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>125</s> 113 bytes

*-8 bytes thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)*

```c
#define T&&*s-
main(s,v)char**v,*s;{for(s=*++v;*s T'a'T'e'T'i'T'o'T'u'||!(*v=memcpy(s-3,"smh",3));++s);puts(*v);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBDoMgEADAe19hNRFY4OSR@As@QFasJKLEVRJT@3bKYW6D@oNYSjf5OWy@sX0PpF/RhY2TygIXdwBkBWS@835wGkHKbIAayxyzzFeh2quLPc@bQx6jj5huTnpQLcWlVYMQRkoSJl0n1SHMr5QyufNOAd36Bw)

Comment: [95 bytes](https://tio.run/##FchRDoMgEEXR/67C2lQQdAVsgw1MRqiTVDRgSZratY/jx7nJezi@EJkfU4iUQuO7zpg63hagpMtQe5why@N@cc3a2upkNF6B8ioIEqv4qOO4b5nSHnVblvlZ2sHU3ll79c/ME@zfjRDeJw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 49 bytes

```
	I =INPUT
	I BREAK('aeiou') ='shm'
	OUTPUT =I
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NTwdbTLyA0hAvIcgpydfTWUE9MzcwvVddUsFUvzshV5@L0Dw0BKgCq43L1c/n/P7EoHQA)

`BREAK` "matches zero or more characters provided they are not in the set of characters in the argument string. That is, it matches up to, but not including, a character from the argument string."

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 81 bytes

```c
i;f(char*s){for(i=0;*s-"aeiou"[++i%6];i%6||s++);printf("shm%s"+3*!*s,s-i*!*s/6);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU/bioMwEH1uviI7ICRGaWGhL2n3R4oPIehmIFXJRKRr/XY3sdudh5kz93Ns/W3ttqHuhHUmlCSXbggCryddUg2mxWGCm1JYnBud3PNJSkk9BuxjJ4DcvSBQn@VHSRXVmOPxLPW63Q32Qi4sX@VltLeGX/nCoJt6G3HooWJAsfXehAxNfIxojc94nmfnnIl7/d9y5sNrGMPoTd@@bgzTPjm7B7BVs0Sfi8SOY3p40ilcOOFPO3QiWsmP72SXK1M/6UnEDm9JBfH6i0PFE2dspGaHvPgHxymSAEhwZev2Cw)

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, 149 bytes

```
=IFERROR(REPLACE(A1,1,FIND("$",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"a","$"),"e","$"),"i","$"),"o","$"),"u","$"))-1,"shm"),A1)
```

102 bytes just to find the vowels.  If anybody knows a better way to do this. please share.

From inside out:

- SUBSTITUTE vowels with `$`
- Find the index of the first `$`
- Replace chars before this index with `shm`
- If no vowels, return input.

Comment: 78 bytes `=IFERROR("shm"&MID(A1,MIN(IFERROR(FIND({"a","e","i","o","u"},A1),"")),9^9),A1)`. `9^9` is well over the 2^15-1 character limit for a cell so it works fine in the `MID()` function for all valid inputs.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-p`, 20 bytes

Uses the `;` separator (as `;` is implicitly added via `-p`).

```perl
s;.*?(?=[aeiou]);shm
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoiczsuKj8oPz1bYWVpb3VdKTtzaG0iLCJhcmdzIjoiLXAiLCJpbnB1dCI6ImZ1bmN0aW9uXG5zdGVsbGFyXG5hdHlwaWNhbFxud3d3aGhoYXRcbmFhYWFhYWFhYWFcbmxyclxuYWlycGxhbmVcbnN0b3V0In0=)

---

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-lF/^[^aeiou]+/ -M5.10.0`, 17 bytes

Slightly more cheaty with the regex in the flags, but saves a few bytes

```perl
say@F?(shm,@F):$_
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoic2F5QEY/KHNobSxARik6JF8iLCJhcmdzIjoiLWxGL15bXmFlaW91XSsvXG4tTTUuMTAuMCIsImlucHV0IjoiZnVuY3Rpb25cbnN0ZWxsYXJcbmF0eXBpY2FsXG53d3doaGhhdFxuYWFhYWFhYWFhYVxubHJyXG5haXJwbGFuZVxuc3RvdXQifQ==)

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 531 bytes

```
->+[->[>],[+[-<+]->+[>]<[>+>+<<-]>>[<<+>>-]-[>++<-----]>-----<<[->>-<<]+>>[<<->>[-]]<<[+[-<+]->-]+[-<+]->[[>]<[>+>+<<-]>>[<<+>>-]-[>++<-----]>-<<[->>-<<]+>>[<<->>[-]]<<[+[-<+]->-]+[-<+]->[[>]<[>+>+<<-]>>[<<+>>-]-[>++<-----]>+++<<[->>-<<]+>>[<<->>[-]]<<[+[-<+]->-]+[-<+]->[[>]<[>+>+<<-]>>[<<+>>-]-[>--<-------]>+<<[->>-<<]+>>[<<->>[-]]<<[+[-<+]->-]+[-<+]->[[>]<[>+>+<<-]>>[<<+>>-]----[>+++++<--]>-<<[->>-<<]+>>[<<->>[-]]<<[+[-<+]->-]+[-<+]->[>]]]]]]+[-<+]->]>[>]<-[++[-<+]->>[.>]>-<]>+[[--------->++<]>+.-----------.+++++.<<<.,[.,]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZJBCkIxDEQPlE5OEOYiYRZ@QRDBheD5a1oIbhX@bJIM7WNSerwu9@ftfX3MCVqCSY2sJkzLoCJptAiIzAgjIZRngSVxl4i6yyqyfayGhFR2s6Du8ifq6USr9hxmrQs09RRmaUW1nfbf5amtnrWcQFobTOdiVthMtNbLlOP4yncCjwgf6UOa8@j/8QE)

This implementation is as close to a nested if/else statement as bf allows. Simply checks each letter to see if it's a vowel. If it finds one, it prints "shm", then the vowel, then the rest of the input. If it doesn't, it simply prints out the input from its buffer.

---

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 423 bytes

```
+[--------->++<]>+.-----------.+++++.<->>+[>,[>+>+<<-]>>[<<+>>-]-[>++<-----]>-----<<[->>-<<]+>>[<<->>[-]]<<[<<->>-]<<[>[>+>+<<-]>>[<<+>>-]-[>++<-----]>-<<[->>-<<]+>>[<<->>[-]]<<[<<->>-]<<[>[>+>+<<-]>>[<<+>>-]-[>++<-----]>+++<<[->>-<<]+>>[<<->>[-]]<<[<<->>-]<<[>[>+>+<<-]>>[<<+>>-]-[>--<-------]>+<<[->>-<<]+>>[<<->>[-]]<<[<<->>-]<<[>[>+>+<<-]>>[<<+>>-]----[>+++++<--]>-<<[->>-<<]+>>[<<->>[-]]<<[<<->>-]]]]]+[-<+]->>]>.,[.,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVFLCkJBDDtQpj1ByUVKFj5BEMGF4PnHdvDhUlGz6Yc0pO12O5yvp/vxMifSdhAIEW4vOBoeRiI5kiAiTGRGgDRZ9tgiiytEZNErCItWRZpU7ZVbZ3yr9BeV8v6DTq3yPIP4vU6hLWG5@mSxRn0loCpFH@lDc277zx4)

A shorter version that only works for words with vowels.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 25 bytes

```
≔⌕Ｅθ№aeiouι¹η¿⊕η«shm✂θη»θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYy9CgIxEIRr8xQhVRZiYZ1KBMFCEHyCkNszC7mNlx8b8dljDi2m@JhvxgeXfXKx92Mp9GB9Jp701T31auQpNa5aOaTUlJEEYORhJIAVNEt9YZ9xQa446QAg32J3y7RNSljUkP54j@RxOxySFR@BsaD8VSvY3ufGvlLivn/FLw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⌕Ｅθ№aeiouι¹η
```

Count the number of vowels in each character and find the first `1` i.e. the index of the first vowel in the input.

```
¿⊕η
```

If there was in fact a vowel, then...

```
«shm✂θη»
```

... output the literal string `shm` followed by the input sliced starting at that index.

```
θ
```

Otherwise just output the input string.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 40 bytes

```java
s->s.replaceAll("^.*?([aeiou])","shm$1")
```

Port of the [JavaScript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247758/52210) and [Retina](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247754/52210) answers.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##PVDNTsMwDL7vKayIQ8KySBM3JkA8ALtwnIbkZdma4aVV4raq0J69uKPChyh2vj/ngh2uLsfv0ROWAh8Y088CICYO@YQ@wHZqAT45x3QGr@dLMRuZ3xZyFEaOHraQ4GUsq9ficmhIuO9EWn25xze9wxDrdm@UVaW6PqyVGTcTtWkPJNRZoavjEa6SYDbZ7dH8uZ/qrDvMwKEwPIPq63y0BzwMtiAFW@5we2qT51gn6QMRZos8NNEj2b7vKylki/9liQURs0RNk0TdsnKlochaYhpzN5bFB1G7Onl1jbgwJT2lWCpQ054BWa@fVtPIUUhnrrQxy@T8HWXmX7qNvw)

Or a minor alternative:

```java
s->s.replaceAll("^.*?(?=[aeiou])","shm")
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##PVDNbsIwDL7zFFZOyQiRpt2GGNoDjMuOiEkmBBpm0ipxW1UTz965rJoPUex8f84VO1xdT9@jJywFPjCmnwVATBzyGX2A3dQCfHKO6QJez5di1jK/L@QojBw97CDBZiyrt@JyaEi470Rafbmnrd5u9hhi3R6MsqpUN2XG9URt2iMJdVbo6niCmySYTfYHNH/u5zrrDjNwKAyvoPo6n@wRj4MtSMGWB9ye2@Q51kn6QITZIg9N9Ei27/tKCtnif1liQcQsUdMkUbesXGkospaQxjyMZfFB1G5OXl0jLkxJTymWCtS0Z0DWzy@raeQopAtX2phlcv6BMvMv3cdf)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->             // Method with String as both parameter and return-type:
  s.replaceAll( //  Modify and return the String: Regex-replace all
    "...",      //  these matches
    "...")      //  with these replacements
```

*Regex-explanation 1:*

```python
^.*?([aeiou])    # Match:
^                #  At the start of the string
 .*              #  Match zero or more characters
   ?             #  Which are optional, to give other matches precedence
     [aeiou]     #  Followed by a vowel
    (       )    #  captured in capture group 1

shm$1            # Replacement:
shm              #  Literal "shm"
   $1            #  And the vowel of capture group 1
```

*Regex-explanation 2:*

```python
^.*?([aeiou])    # Match:
^                #  At the start of the string
 .*              #  Match zero or more characters
   ?             #  Which are optional, to give other matches precedence
    (?=       )  #  Followed by a positive (non-matching) look-ahead to:
       [aeiou]   #   A vowel

shm              # Replacement:
shm              #  Literal "shm"
```

Minor note: the `replaceAll` with `^` is basically the same as a `replaceFirst` without the `^`, but 1 byte shorter: [try it online](https://tio.run/##PVC9bsMgEN7zFCfUARqCFHVrlHbr1iwdowwXjGNSgi0427KqPLt7pFZvQNzx/R1XHHBzrb5nGzBn@EQff1YAPpJLNVoHh9ICfFHy8QJWLpesdjy/r/jIhOQtHCDCfs6bt2yS6wJzP3zKJIV5fpdHdL7tT0pokZvb01aoeVe4XX8OzF0khtZXcOMIi8vxhOrPvm6THDABuUzwCmJsU6XPeJ50xuB0fsB13UdLvo3cuxAwaaSp8xaDHsex4ULS@F86ECN84qyxSLQ9CZO74DmzFko9jHnzidVuhl9Nxy4Uoiwp1gJEWdQhye3LpoxMcPFCjVRqHY19oNTyTff5Fw).

Comment: Java is shorter than Python. What is going on...

Comment: It's really a regex solution :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [V (Eh, vim shmim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 23 bytes

```
:%s/.\{-}\ze[aeiou]/shm
```

vim non-greedy regex with look-ahead.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcsxDoAgDEDRvfdwVHavIg4NwZSkAoEiQePZkck/v3/1vk5ZLfqZX33bDa0LZVeZzt6P4o244CGLZcYEKC06gwy1ViJCAfwDTgO4FBm9HUcoApXaBw)

Same in “magic very very” mode:

## 23 bytes

```
:%s/\v.{-}[aeiou]@=/shm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PctBCoAgEEDR/dyjZbkPgu5RLQYxRphUdFQkOru16q/fL73PQ1J7me7x2dBYn491UYmu3s/stFjvIIlhxggoLViNDLVWIkIB/AOOH7AxMDrzHT4LVGov)

Further 3 bytes can be saved by replacing `:%s/` with V’s specific `í`

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), <s>58</s> 57 bytes

```
f s|g s>""="shm"++g s|1>0=s
g=dropWhile(`notElem`"aeiou")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PVCxbgIxDN35CstiAF2R2g2kJlu3MjF0aJEwkLuLmkuixNEJiT_pwoLY-zf9GxKO4sF-z7aen_xzaSl-K2NOp3Piejb_W9QQjw1EiSgwth1WVWbHF_ks4qgR--D8R6uNmmys4zejug2S0i7h9C7w25G2IKAjvwSfeMXh3cIYJl8RZhIiVBUgCJlTRvnaFF7HEj6xd2GPT4Bb2h5KjWTUrXLQtimoTnbH2tmhm11TKJD44PWOTMF937c5iG-DRxRmeNjWwRuyd2mXGNeD8_8XXAE)

*-1 byte thanks to Wheat Wizard ♦*

Answer (score 2):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 15 bytes

```
a~XVaH$(:"shm"a
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhbrE-siwhI9VDSslIozcpUSIaJQyTXRSomZRQU5iXmpSrFQMQA)

#### Explanation

```
a~XVaH$(:"shm"a
a                Command-line argument
 ~               Find first match of
  XV             regex `[aeiou]`
      $(         Index of that match
    aH           Prefix of cmdline arg containing that many characters
        :        Set to
         "shm"   that string
                 If a vowel was not found, $( is nil, which means no assignment is done
                 and a's value remains unchanged
              a  Autoprint the (possibly changed) value of a
```

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 31 bytes

```apl
{⍵≢⍛≡n←⌊/⍵⍳'aeoiu':⍵⋄'shm',n↓⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9NCsIwEEb3PUV2UbDo2hu48gyhTU0gpqVNqUXciVC1IogrV3oF8UK5SEzS/2YRmDfvG2ZQxFw/RyzcuHgnMPexr@TtuVrL032hAv3vZfmTxUeWL1m8uQbyep4bVn4hwiFN4dJUlyNMyBbOtPHQ9UGpSQBgkHJP0JBDAKZA54GRGuYYIxGYMRRroWdUyPaRyCPqITaY0EKrZFlGCEFipNT59sFes4NWYrFdAHRLGFLlaRwxxPFweAPrE8JUwH5aKwZV25F8NNsQ5w8)

Comment: 29: [`{(∨/⊃⍵⍮'shm',⍵/⍨∨\)⍵∊'aeiou'}`](https://tio.run/##XY89DoIwGIZ3TtGtkEjwGk5ewKWBYkkqJVCCxDiZGCTBuHgANyY3L9SL1Lb806Fpnu95v7xFCXWDElF2dPGZ4zjAgRTP924v7q@tDNV9sUXVeqK@ieYnmi/MyAlu1NsTTasmB0fzqoYIRyyHVyntEMAwj30esRgC4ADx@AAdG5iljYxjSlGqhJnRITNHvEwiH9HFhhEapSgKQgjiK6XPjwfOhhM0Ek1NATCV0KTLR2lCUYyXywfYf4HlHM7TStGoa0fK1W5NrD8 "APL (Dyalog Extended) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator), 114 bytes

```
s="a"
InputBox(s)
S=Take(s,IndexOf(Element(Split(s,Split("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz",{""})),1),s))
If(S=="",s,"shm"+S)
```

Not sure why, but the code won't work if you put in an empty string as initial value of `s` (or any string consisting of only consonants), but it will work properly for all test cases (even ones that do consist of only consonants) if you have a string with a vowel as the initial value of `s`.

The input should be entered into the Input Box.

[Try It On GeoGebra!](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/qtamphyp)

Answer (score 2):

## [Lexurgy](https://www.lexurgy.com/sc), <s>42</s> 40 bytes

```php
a:
(!{a,e,i,o,u})*=>shm/$ _ {a,e,i,o,u}
```

Finds 0 or more not vowels at the start of input before a vowel and replaces them with `shm`.

- -2 bytes by not using classes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 103 bytes

```go
import."regexp"
func f(s string)string{return MustCompile(`^.*?([aeiou])`).ReplaceAllString(s,"shm$1")}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PY_PSsQwEMbPzlOE4CFZ1oI3EURE8CaIHkXtUKdtME1CMqEuy76Bb-BlEXyofRvT7bpzmT98M99vvn86v90tAjYf2JEY0DgwQ_CRK9kOLI9N4mhcl-Rv5vbsYtf9zyN19BkktNk1olVJzEI9p3UkztGJ-5z41g_BWFL1a7W4Vs9IxucXXevqkYLFhm6sfdovqbSUqR9Oz6XeHOy-9ucnOqXFGlofxdsyicsrEdEV7jtD9j2pepKx8Q4Sk7UYAXkVTIMWxnHs-x4Z8BhgYxGYWNwdlQ2fGcZ-BTN6PRmdPJSSrStI03NawwYOTNvtnP8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [tinylisp 2](https://github.com/dloscutoff/tinylisp2), <s>64</s> 61 bytes

```lisp
(\(S)(: T(drop-while(. !(p contains?"aeiou"))S)(? T(,"shm"T)S
```

Try it at [Replit](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/tinylisp2). Example session:

```lisp
tl2> (\(S)(: T(drop-while(. !(p contains?"aeiou"))S)(? T(,"shm"T)S
(() (S) (: T (drop-while (. ! (p contains? "aeiou")) S) (? T (, "shm" T) S)))
tl2> (def shm _)
shm
tl2> (map shm (list "codegolf" "stellar" "airplane" "lrr"))
("shmodegolf" "shmellar" "shmairplane" "lrr")
```

#### Explanation

Port of [Unrelated String's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247761/16766), among others.

First, we need a function that tests whether a character is not a vowel:

```lisp
(. !(p contains?"aeiou"))
(.                      ) ; Compose
   !                      ; Logical negation
    (p                 )  ; with the partial application of
       contains?          ; the contains? function
                "aeiou"   ; to "aeiou"
```

Then our main function is as follows (where `(...)` represents the above function):

```lisp
(\(S)(: T(drop-while(...)S)(? T(,"shm"T)S)))
(\                                         ) ; Lambda function
  (S)                                        ; that takes a string S:
     (: T                                 )  ;  In what follows, let T be
         (drop-while     S)                  ;   Drop characters from S while
                    (...)                    ;   they are not vowels
                           (? T          )   ;  Is T truthy (nonempty)?
                               (,"shm"T)     ;  If so, concatenate "shm" with T
                                        S    ;  If not, return the original string S
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 15.5 bytes

```
?,;>~$-~?"aeiou"$:"shm"@@
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWO-11rO3qVHTr7JUSUzPzS5VUrJSKM3KVHBwg8lBl66KVYpSKS4oy89JjlJRioaIA)

Nibbles has no built-in for vowels, which makes it slightly worse than other golfing languages for this.

### Explanation

```
?         If
,          non-empty
;           x :=
>~           drop-while
$             from input
-~            not
? "aeiou"      contained in "aeiou"
$              it
          then
: "shm"    prepend "shm"
@          to x
          else
@          input
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 11 bytes

```
Aa[ᶤAİ"=ᵐ„p
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCJBYVvhtqRBxLBcIj3htZDigJ5wIiwiIiwiaGVsbG8gd29ybGQiLCIzLjQuMiJd)

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 5.9, <s>67</s> <s>63</s> 62 bytes

```swift
let f={s in{$0>"" ?"shm"+$0:s}(s.drop{!"aeiou".contains($0)})}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Uiua, 25 bytes

```
⟨◌|⊂"shm"▽\↥⟩∊1.∊,"aeiou"
```

[Try it](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__RiDihpAg4p-o4peMfOKKgiJzaG0i4pa9XOKGpeKfqeKIijEu4oiKLCJhZWlvdSIKRiAiY29kZWdvbGYiCkYgIndoeSIK)

This one’s pretty simple but I’ll leave an explanation for those who can’t read Uiua:

```
∊,"aeiou"
```

Create a mask of the input where there are vowels.

```
⟨…|…⟩∊1.
```

Check if the mask contains any 1s. If it does:

```
⊂"shm"▽\↥
```

Scan by maximum (`[0 0 1 0 1 0]` gives `[0 0 1 1 1 1]`), use this as filter over the input, and prepend “shm”.

Otherwise:

```
◌
```

Discard the mask, leaving just the input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>70</s> <s>61</s> 45 bytes

```factor
[ R/ ^[^aeiou]*(?=[aeiou])/ "shm"re-replace ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYsxC8IwFAb3/ooPJxW0uyKO4uKgOJUWHuHVBtIkfX0hivjba0HwphvuWjIaZLrfzpfTDkOG8IOfESMPib3hEVFY9RXFesW@KIb8Rpu8URs8RmXnSEBzYA055Jy7riMF/YGTObASHXmej5AUn6nCtURTNcQ2pHq9PB6qn65KLMauXwhvhOfHMOqpp4jt9AU)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 39 bytes

```lua
print((...):gsub("^.-%f[aeiou]","shm"))
```

Uses the frontier pattern to shave off two bytes. String must be provided as argument, printed output is (1) the shmodegolfed string and (2) 0 if unmodified, 1 if modified.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RDQ09PT9Mqvbg0SUMpTk9XNS06MTUzvzRWSUepOCNXSVPz////aaV5ySWZ@XkA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) with `-m32`, <s>90</s> <s>85</s> <s>83</s> 79 bytes

- -2 thanks to ceilingcat
- -4 by removing an unused variable

```c
v;f(char*s){for(v=s;v**s;)index("aeiou",*s++)&&printf("shm",v=0);puts(v?:--s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3BbsMgEETv@YqVpUaAbalqb0VOv2VFjEHC2AIMjSL/ere4UdM97czbmVX9pBRRlpopg0FEftdLYHmIMgsRJbf@On6xBke7bE0nYtvy83kN1ifNmmjmpsvDK5frliLLnx99H7ncqWKY0Xp2LBgm1cFRD0JUkTncTwDHHwmibQ9LPjyAv@qXCMMFmg4eCfkLNftX@2knumK6rVahI715leziKabROQz0JKUUYwwmwueQC/XAhtWhH2ti2RIVc6MKvpV2OEXqC/Xz@9sP)

Answer (score 1):

## Batch, <s>157</s> 145 bytes

```
@set i=%1
:l
@(echo %i:~,1%|findstr/r [aeiou]&&set a=1||set a=0)>nul
@if %a%==0 (if %i%. neq . (set i=%i:~1%&goto:l)else echo %1)else echo shm%i%
```

Input is taken from the command line.

-12 bytes thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil).

Comment: Can you not just `echo %1` and `echo shm%i%` rather than setting `i`?

Answer (score 1):

## [StackCell](https://esolangs.org/wiki/StackCell), 83

`(@:{X}X:'a-!?6:'e-!?6:'i-!?6:'o-!?6:'u-!?3!)6"mhs"16:[;:]18(@:!?.;)X{:[{X}X:]X:[;:]`

Explanation (for a previous, incomplete version of the program):

```
(@:'a-!?6:'e-!?6:'i-!?6:'o-!?6:'u-!?2!)"mhs":[;:](@:!?.;) Assumes the input contains a vowel
(                                     )                   Loop over the initial characters, breaking if ) is reached with a non-zero value
 @                                                        Input a character
  :'a-                                                    Duplicate and calculate the difference with the character 'a'
      !?                                                  If there is any difference, skip the next instruction
        6                                                 Skip 6 instructions (to next 6)
         :'e-!?6:'i-!?6:'o-!?6:'u-!?2                     Check the other four vowels; the 2 breaks out of the loop
                                     !                    Negate the character; EOF => 1, anything else => 0
                                       "mhs"              Push the characters mhs to the stack
                                            :[;:]         Print the characters s, h, m, and the vowel that caused the initial loop to break
                                                 (      ) Loop forever (a non-zero value will never be present at the end of the loop
                                                  @:      Input and duplicate a character
                                                    !?.;  If it's non-null (EOF), print it. Otherwise, halt.
```